# Create a newline for every x number of characters

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have an arbitrary string that has x number of characters. How can I insert a newline char in the string for every y characters? I just want to wrap the string, so that this:

```
xageaojigeaogjieaogjieaogjoajgoeajgoeagjaegaogjeaovc
```

becomes

```
xageaoj
igeaogj
ieaogji
eaogjoa
jgoeajg
oeagjae
gaogjea
ovc
```

if the line wrap count is 7. One way would be to loop over the string and then push to array, something like this:

```
const wrap = (count, str) => {
  const letters = [], ln = str.length;

  for(let i = 0; i < ln; i++){
    letters.push(str[i]);
    if(i%count === 0)
    letters.push('\n');
  }

  return letters.join('');
};
```

but is there a better/simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You might use a regular expression `.replace`:

```js
const input = 'xageaojigeaogjieaogjieaogjoajgoeajgoeagjaegaogjeaovc';
console.log(input.replace(/.{8}/g, '$&\n'));
```

What this does is, every 8 characters are matched (with `.{8}`), and then `'$&'` in the second argument represents the whole substring that was matched. So, just tack on a `\n` to the end, and every 8 characters will be replaced with those 8 characters plus a newline. You can also insert matched *groups* like this, among other things - see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

Comment: thanks, can you explain how that regex works? What is the `$&` doing exactly?

Comment: that is nifty, will try it out, Mexican style

Answer (score 1):

`RegExp` + `Array.prototype.join` version:

```js
const wrap = (raw, n) => raw.match(new RegExp(`.{1,${n}}`, 'g')).join('\n')

const source = 'xageaojigeaogjieaogjieaogjoajgoeajgoeagjaegaogjeaovc'

console.log(wrap(source, 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach could be to use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) with an indicator for the next index for slicing.

```js
const wrap = (str, count) => {
    var letters = [],
        i = 0;

    while (i < str.length) {
        letters.push(str.slice(i,  i+= count));
    }
    return letters.join('\n');
};

console.log(wrap('xageaojigeaogjieaogjieaogjoajgoeajgoeagjaegaogjeaovc', 7));
```

Comment: yeah I decided to make the number/integer the first arg, easier to read otherwise, looks nifty

Comment: it would serve better, if `count` gets a default value.

Comment: yes, and also my solution in the OP fails because 0%0 === 0

Comment: or wait, actually it equals NaN, dunno why I get a newline as the second char then, hmmm

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to match 7 characters and replace them with the match followed by a new line

```
str.replace(/(.{7})/g, "$1\n")
```

or in your code

```
const wrap = (str, count) =>
    str.replace(new RegExp(`(.{${count}})`, "g"), "$1\n")
```